# Searching an exact match for the attribute of a relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I have following SQLAlchemy DB models describing parts that go through several production steps:

```
class Part(db.Model):
    part_number = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    production_steps = db.relationship("ProductionStep")


class ProductionStep(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    part_number = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('part.part_number'))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
```

Now I'd like to query **all parts that have a production step with a certain name and status** through a Flask-Restless [search query](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/searchformat.html).

Is this possible with a Flask-Restless search query? If yes, how can I achieve the specified behaviour?

I'm using Flask-Restless version 0.17.0.

---

I have tried following filters:

```
q={"filters":[{"and":[{"name":"production_steps__name","op":"==","val":"cutting"},
    {"name":"production_steps__status","op":"any","val":"done"}]}]}
```

Which leads to following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership.

Which sounds reasonable, so I also tried the following:

```
q={"filters":[{"and":
    [{"name":"production_steps","op":"any","val":{"name":"name","op":"eq","val":"cutting"}},
    {"name":"production_steps","op":"any","val":{"name":"status","op":"eq","val":"done"}}]
}]}
```

This query does work, but it does return parts that match only one of the criterions (e.g. parts with a production step "cutting" where the status is not "done")

Comment: The last query has 2 separate EXISTS subquery expressions, so you do get what it asks for, but you'd need to include both predicates in a single EXISTS expression, which Flask-Restless would not seem to support at the moment, at least on a glance.

Comment: Yeah I guess your right. I haven't found any way to do this in the meantime, so I'd accept your explanations as an answer if you bother to write one. Thanks for looking into it anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, **Flask-Restless does not seem to support queries like this.**

Two possible workarrounds:

1. Do two search queries: First get all Ids of ProductionSteps with the correct name and status. Second query all Parts that have one of Ids in the production_steps array with the `in` operator.
2. Implement your own route that returns the Parts wanted. Code might look something like this:

   ```
   @app.route('/part/outstanding', methods=['GET'])
   def parts_outstanding():

       result = Part.query.join(Part.production_steps) \
           .filter_by(status='outstanding').all()

       #Custom serialization logic
       result_json = list(map(lambda part: part.to_dict(), result))
       return jsonify(
           num_results=len(result),
           objects=result_json,
           page=1,
           total_pages=1
       )
   ```

I'd advocate for doing two search queries. Implementing your own route seems kinda hacky.